# design 220V dc to 420V dc boost converter

Tags: ups

What I can use instead of an INDUCTOR in BOOS converter to step up voltage from 220V DC to 420V DC to charge a power bank (battery)?

Comment: Output current/power? Necessity for isolation?

Comment: *Is it possible to design* Think about that sentence. If I was to say yes or no, that would both be an answer. Both answers would be pretty useless. *however, designing boost converter we cannot find high inductance inductor with high current ratings?* That is a confusing sentence. Be more specific about your needs. But then it turns into a shopping question which is not allowed here.

Comment: There are quite a few reference designs online, TI (Texas Instruments) and Fairchild (now owned by ON Semi) have quite a portfolio of high capacity power supply designs along with full schematics and bill of materials.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a 'high inductance inductor with high current ratings'. You do need a 'suitable inductor' for your converter specification.

When you buy an inductor, you are basically buying energy storage. The more the inductor costs (in weight, volume, dollars) then generally the more energy it will store.

You need to specify the power throughput, and an operating frequency for your converter, which will then give you an amount of energy you need to store per cycle in the inductor. Once you have looked through a few inductor catalogues, can can establish a budget for how much it costs to store that amount of energy. Then you can have a more directed search for components that meet you specification.

You can use multiple inductors. Either simplistically, connecting several in series, to raise the inductance. Or more cleverly, building a polyphase converter, which eases the input and output ripple requirements. Or building several completely separate converters, that when paralleled, can share the load current between them, this latter one offers you scalability, graceful fallback in the event of one breaking, ability to hold spares and hot-swap, all sorts of good things.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the magnetics used in converters (especially of the high voltage or high power type) is custom. You can pick a core and a bobbin and design your own inductor if none appear to meet your requirements. Subject to market forces, laws of physics, ability etc.

In this particular case it perhaps could even be done without inductors- with an oscillator + half-bridge driving a voltage doubler.